# How to receive the message of a UINavigationBar Cancel or Done button?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uistoryboard

I can add a Cancel or Done button to a UINavigationBar in Interface Builder. But how do I hook these up to action methods so I can close the modal view controller or save the input and then close it?

The connections panel doesn't show any action methods for a UIBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in code, in the viewDidLoad or awakeFromNib methods. First, you need to create the button, and add a method to be called when the buttons are pushed.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];

    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:doneButton animated:NO];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    //TODO
}
```

- OR

Alternatively, in IB, make your IBAction method,

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender {

}
```

and declare it in your Class.h,

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender;
```

Then in IB, right click on the Button and drag from 'Selector' to your file's owner (the view controller) and select the doneButtonPressed: method.